# Ways to provide a user group access to a S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm restricting bucket access to my VPC Endpoints, I have a bucket say test-bucket, I have added the below policy to enable the access to be restricted to only through the VPC Endpoints:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Access From Dev, QA Account",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "NotPrincipal": {
                "AWS": arn:aws:iam::x:root"                
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetBucketLocation",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:ListBucket"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::test-bucket",
                "arn:aws:s3:::test-bucket/*"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "StringNotEquals": {
                    "aws:sourceVpce": [
                        "vpce-1234",
                        "vpce-1235"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
```

This policy block console, awscli access to all users, provides only instances in the VPC to gain access to s3 bucket, i have a user group called D which consist of 40 users, I cannot add the group arn to principal as AWS doesn't support it, but it is tedious to add all the 40 users to the bucket policy. We are denying all traffic as we are making our objects Public, as this bucket is used as a yum repo and have to be available over https for the instances to download during a yum install/update. Kindly advice on how to give access using that users group D or is there any way around to provide users access ?

Comment: To make it unequivocal–group mean–IAM group OR Cognito user group?

Comment: How are the IAM Users accessing the objects? Are they using IAM User credentials on their own computers to access the bucket, or are they accessing the bucket via Amazon EC2 instances?

Comment: @Tejas Will take a look at the Cognito user group, Thanks

Comment: @JohnRotenstein access from EC2 to bucket works fine with the above policy, but when IAM user uses his creds to access he will be denied access due to the above policy.

Comment: I wonder whether [Managing data access with Amazon S3 access points](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/access-points.html) would be a solution? It's rather new.

Answer (score 0):

The group is not a principal which means you would be limited to the arn of the IAM user in this specific condition.

As a workaround you could create an IAM role that is able to be assumed either [through the console](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_use_switch-role-console.html) or [via the CLI](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/sts/assume-role.html). Then ensure that the S3 bucket policy specified the arn of the IAM role instead. Finally allow the users in the group to assume the IAM role.